# Google Apps: Tag contact as "My Contacts", sync?

Tags: google-workspace, google-contacts, synchronization

Using Google Apps.  I have Mac Address Book, iOS Contacts set to synchronize with the account.

If I create contacts manually via web interface, they synchronize beautifully with all devices.

But if I look up a contact in the Directory and add it to the My Contacts group, I see the following behavior:

- On the web interface in the My Contacts group, I see the contact listed with its name, email and phone; and the detail page shows the connected profiles and directory contact info.  It only populates the Work email, name and title fields (not phone), but I can see the extra info in the linked profiles.
- On my iOS devices, no contact entry is created.  (Again, note above, when I create a new contact manually it instantly pushes to iOS.)
- In Mac's Address Book, the contact appears but ONLY the email is populated; no name, no title, no phone.

Am I out of luck here?  I'm trying to get a few dozen co-workers to synch to my phone without having to manually create them.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I manually edited at least one field, the contact now syncs.